# Hibernate 4.3.0.Final get session

Tags: java, hibernate, configuration, sessionfactory

In the [hibernate documentation for version 4.3.0.Final](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch01.html#tutorial-firstapp-helpers) the following code snippet is given to create a `SessionFactory`:

```
package org.hibernate.tutorial.util;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
            return new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        }
        catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

}
```

This seems to be outdated, as the method `buildSessionFactory()` is deprecated. What is the correct way to create the `SessionFactory`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
public class TestHB4 {
    private static StandardServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person person = new Person();
        person.setFirstName("Namal");
        person.setLastName("Dinesh");


        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
        serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
        sessionFactory = configuration.configure().buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

        session.beginTransaction();

        session.save(person);

        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();


    }
```

Comment: would you have a look at my question as well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23646389/how-to-get-session-in-hibernate-4-3-4-final

Comment: Thank you! (I wonder when are they going to decide to stop changing this)

Comment: In this answer `Configuration.configure()` has been called twice. As I think this could lead to throw exceptions like `Duplicate class/entity mapping` because configurations are parsed twised. I think 10th line of this code should be changed as `sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);`. Correct me if I am wrong.