# How to configure and get session in Hibernate 4.3.4.Final?

Tags: java, hibernate, configuration, transactions, c3p0

I recently upgraded the version of my Hibernate to 4.3.4.Final. [Based on Contextual Sessions configuration of Hibernate this new version is not based on ThreadLocal anymore.](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/architecture.html#architecture-current-session) If what I have got so far is correct do I need to do anything to make it more efficient? if it is incorrect what should I do? I have no clue.

**Please note** it is mentioned in documentation that: Hibernate offers three methods of current session tracking. The "thread" based method is not intended for production use; it is merely useful for prototyping and tutorials such as this one.

**Hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>

    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/myDB</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property>
        <!--        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>-->

        <mapping class="com.myProject.entities.users" />
        ...
```

**Current Configuration and Code**

Based on answers blew and [this part of documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#tutorial-firstapp-workingpersistence) mu current configuration is as 
following:

```
 public class HibernateUtil {

    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
              Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
              return configuration.configure()
                                  .buildSessionFactory(
                                       new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()  
                                          .applySettings(configuration.getProperties())
                                          .build());
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

}
```

And the code would be as following

```
    final Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    try {
        final Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        try {
              ...
```

**Previous Configuration and Code**

```
public class HibernateUtil {

    private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;
    private static final ThreadLocal<Session> threadLocal = new ThreadLocal();
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private static SessionFactory configureSessionFactory() {
        try {
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.configure();
            serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                    .applySettings(configuration.getProperties())
                    .build();
            sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
            return sessionFactory;
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            System.out.append("** Exception in SessionFactory **");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    static {
        try {
            sessionFactory = configureSessionFactory();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("%%%% Error Creating SessionFactory %%%%");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private HibernateUtil() {
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static Session getSession() throws HibernateException {
        Session session = threadLocal.get();

        if (session == null || !session.isOpen()) {
            if (sessionFactory == null) {
                rebuildSessionFactory();
            }
            session = (sessionFactory != null) ? sessionFactory.openSession() : null;
            threadLocal.set(session);
        }

        return session;
    }

    public static void rebuildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            sessionFactory = configureSessionFactory();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("%%%% Error Creating SessionFactory %%%%");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void closeSession() throws HibernateException {
        Session session = (Session) threadLocal.get();
        threadLocal.set(null);
        if (session != null) {
            if (session.isOpen()) {
                session.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code to access to transactions and submit commands

```
 final Session session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
        try {
            final Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
            try {

                    //Commands related to query go here

             if (!tx.wasCommitted()) {
                    tx.commit();
                }

                if (session.isOpen()) {
                    session.close();
                }

                return true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                tx.rollback();
                return false;
            }
        } finally {
            HibernateUtil.closeSession();
        }
        return false;
```

Comment: As the Hibernate documentation states, you should not use the properties to configure the database connection, instead use a DataSource like c3p0 or state the JNDI name of the data source.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza would you refer me to an example or tutorial of that?

Comment: [Hibernate 4.3.5 final Documentation. Chapter 3. Configuration. 3.3. JDBC connections](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch03.html#configuration-hibernatejdbc): *Hibernate's own connection pooling algorithm is, however, quite rudimentary. It is intended to help you get started and is not intended for use in a production system, or even for performance testing. You should use a third party pool for best performance and stability.* (Continue reading in the link)

Comment: I just connected the code to c3p0 and it works with my current code. Back to my original question how to get sessions? is the code that I have sufficient?

Comment: What do you mean by *how to get sessions*?

Comment: I already configured c3p0 as my connection pool, is the HibernateUtil class sufficient for production system or I need to change it?

Comment: There are other frameworks that help you with this like Spring, and AFAIK I haven't seen a live system using that. You can search for that, though

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Sorry but I do not get you, I rephrase my question, not I am using hibernate in conjunction with c3p0. I am using a class called HibernateUtil to retrieve new sessions. Do you think it is sufficient for production system? or I need to retrieve sessions in another way?

Comment: And I said that I haven't seen any live production system that works like that because you use Hibernate with another libraries like Spring that handle that for you.

Comment: I see, do you have any example of that? or any tutorial?\

Comment: You may search them on the net.

Comment: What should I search on ? I mean based on which phrases, sorry but I am totally confused.

Comment: Hibernate spring get session maybe? Seriously, you have to try how to search stuff on the net as much as you try/fail/try/fail/try/success, similar to programming.

Comment: I know but I did not get what is the topic that I should look for. Any way thanks for your help. I will do some research on it.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza question is updated now.

Answer (score 3):

I would drop the TreadUtil class which reminds me of the Spring 1.0 Hibernate integration style. If you plan on moving to Hibernate 4.

Beside the fact that you should rely on Hibernate 4 [bootstrap](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/hem/en-US/html_single/#setup-configuration-bootstrapping) mechanism, your code also has the following problems:

1. The session factory rebuilding is not synchronized

   ```
       synchronized(HibernateUtil.class) {
       if (sessionFactory == null) {
           rebuildSessionFactory();
       }
   }
   ```
2. I don't see why you need to rebuild it, since you never set it to null, the session factory being initialized static block.

If you always have to wrap your Hibernate code in the HibernateUtil.openSession() try/finally blocks, you would duplicate a lot of session management logic while mixing business logic with transaction logic. This breaks the single responsibility principle.

If you still don't want to let the HibernateUtil go, you can at least use a mechanism similar to [JDBCTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html) to abstract the session/transaction management in a template method, while supplying the business code in a Callable, which for you might look like:

```
interface SessionCallback<T> {T doInSession(Session session);}

class HibernateUtil {

    public T execute(SessionCallback<T> action) {
        try{
            //open session
            //open transcation
            T result = action.doInSession(sessionFactory.getCurrentSession());
            //commit tx



            return result;
        }
        catch(RuntimeException e) {
            //rollback tx
            throw e;
        }
        finally {
            //close session
        }
    }
}

HibernateUtil.execute(new SessionCallback<Void>() {
    public Void doInSession(Session session) {
        session.createQuery(...);
        return null;
    }
});

final customerID = ...

Customer customer = HibernateUtil.execute(new SessionCallback<Customer>() {
    public Customer doInSession(Session session) {
        return (Customer) session.get(Customer.class, customerID);
        return null;
    }
});
```

Looking at your code indicates you want JDBC resource local transactions with the session-per-request access idiom, meaning you need the ThreadLocalSessionContext:

```
hibernate.current_session_context_class=thread
hibernate.transaction.factory_class=JDBCTransactionFactory
```

Extra

You might consider switching to JPA as well and moving the Hibernate properties to persistence.xml.

Comment: whats your idea about vanOekel's answer? question is also updated.

Comment: I think both him and I agree there's no need for the HibernateUtil class and mixing the session management with the application business logic. I updated my response to show you how you could at least separate the transaction management from the application code, if you still want to keep the Util class.

Comment: Actually, I do not want to keep the Util class, I am just intended to follow the best practice. Have you checked out my new solution based on Hibernate documentation?

Comment: I see you set to 'thread' the session context policy which is good, you got rid of the custom made Thread Local storage. If you use Spring you get the transaction management for free. Otherwise a transaction template mechanism, as the one I described in my updated response, would help you separating concerns.

Comment: thanks, in that case, as I am not using spring, is what I did in "Current Configuration and Code" part of my question correct?

Comment: @JackMoore The session factory instantiation looks ok, but you should know that the latest documentation doesn't contain much references to the Hibernate specific API. Hibernate has been updated considerably to accommodate the JPA specs. That's why the bootstrapping example uses the JPA related classes. While it may work either way, I would go for the JPA configuration style.

Answer (score 2):

Access to a single instance of SessionFactory within your aplication is all that is needed.

The following information is all (available) from the Hibernate 4.3 manual chapters [2.2. Contextual sessions](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#architecture-current-session) and 
[13. Transactions and Concurrency](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#transactions).

"A **SessionFactory** is an expensive-to-create, threadsafe object, intended to be shared by all application threads. It is created once, usually on application startup, from a Configuration instance."

"A **Session** is an inexpensive, non-threadsafe object that should be used once and then discarded for: a single request, a conversation or a single unit of work."

If there is no "unit of work" but just a bunch of (bundled) queries and updates, simply follow the first idiom for the [non-managed environment](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#transactions-demarcation-nonmanaged) (from chapter 13 mentioned earlier). And unless you can demonstrate this gives performance problems(*), do not try to optimize because that is the [root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization).

If there is a "unit of work" or "session-per-request", the `HibernateUtil` from the question can be replaced by using `org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext` as `CurrentSessionContext` (see chapter 2.2 mentioned earlier) and following the second idiom for the [non-managed environment](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#transactions-demarcation-nonmanaged).

If you use JTA, replace `ThreadLocalSessionContext` with `org.hibernate.context.internal.JTASessionContext` and follow the idioms described in [Using JTA](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#transactions-demarcation-jta).

Pay attention to the chapter that discusses the "unit of work": a good architecture for your software depends on a good understanding of what a "business transaction" and "application transaction" means for your application.

(*) Performance problems can be caused by configuration problems, e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3924079/3080094) which has related documentation  [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#transactions-connection-release) in the Hibernate manual.

Comment: Thanks for the info, the question is that my code is not able to access getCurrentSession() method of sessionFactory class as suggested in the documentation. is the current code fine or I should amend it? Another thing is that I have various methods, and in each a session will be retrieved, transaction will begin and end before returnign the result to client, based on what you said I suppose I am following the correct method. Although I am not sure about my sessionFactory as mentionedabove.

Comment: 1) `org.hibernate.SessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` is a method that exists, something is very wrong if you cannot access it. 2) Delete the HibernateUtil.open/closeSession() methods. Use the idiom from the Hibernate documentation in combination with  `HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession()`. 3) You should be fine but the Hibernate manual warns that you should "consider session-per-operation an anti-pattern" (chapter 1.1.7).

Comment: I am still a bit confused but I could solve the problem and get access to the getCurrentSession method, question is updated now.